# Support Ticket permission problem

Tags: 7, users

I have been trying to get the [support ticket system module](https://www.drupal.org/project/support) to work and for some reason I got a problem few problems.

My clients cannot post support tickets or cannot see them.

Every time my client try to post a support ticket they got this error:

> Unable to subscribe user, USERNAME does not have permission to view
>   this ticket.

And if my client try to see a post that the administrator post they got an access denied.

My understanding is that this problem it was with the permission. So I gave the clients all permission except to administrate the module.

These are the permission that they have

**Support**

- Can administer state
- Can suppress notification
- Can subscribe other users to notifications
- Download mail via support/fetch
- View other users tickets
- Can select state
- Can select priority
- Can select client
- Can assign tickets to self
- Can assign tickets to any user
- Access CLIENT tickets.

**Node**

- Support ticket: Create new content
- Support ticket: Edit own content
- Support ticket: Delete own content
  -

I have follow all the steps from the INSTALL.txt from the module.
I have rebuild my permissions.

How can I troubleshoot this problem ? I'm doing something wrong ?

[EDIT]

I figure out that if I give the user this permission `Administer support` they are going to have access to view this tickets. But they also have access to do anything with the module something that I dont want.

Comment: Is this D6 or D7?

Comment: D7... it seem to me like a bug. So I ended up using a third-party application, [trello](https://trello.com/), which is different but it help me solve my issue.

Comment: You're probably right about that bug. I've ben using this module in D6 in the past. Also ran into some bugs and behaviours in that module I didn't really like. Which is why we build our own Dupal based Support System, rather simple (some content types, views, etc), but works great. Modelled after Bugzilla. We're now upgrading it to D7, and consider publishing it as a Distribution on D.O some day ...